# Unable to install docker on Amazon linux

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to install docker on Amazon Linux Ec2 instance, I get the following error.

Installing docker

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Cleaning repos: amzn2-core amzn2extra-docker amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2 amzn2extra-php7.2 docker-ce-stable
4 metadata files removed
0 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                             | 3.7 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-docker                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-lamp-mariadb10.2-php7.2                                                                                                                                                     | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
amzn2extra-php7.2                                                                                                                                                                      | 3.0 kB  00:00:00
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/2/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (Docker CE Stable - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=docker-ce-stable ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable docker-ce-stable
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=docker-ce-stable

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=docker-ce-stable.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-ce-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/2/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Installation failed. Check that you have permissions to install.
[root@ip-172-31-79-10 ec2-user]# ^C
[root@ip-172-31-79-10 ec2-user]# chkconfig docker on
error reading information on service docker: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Remove the docker repo you added and `yum install docker` should work.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem when I tried to install docker on a centos machine
I followed the official guide [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/) and found out the commad:

```
sudo yum-config-manager \
--add-repo \
https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

messed up the installation..

my solution was:

1. delete the installed docker-repo:

   sudo rm /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
2. install docker: sudo yum install docker

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was ablet o remove it and start the install from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

## Follow official guide!

[image]

You can find it in the below link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-container-image.html